Sticky header doesnt work with z-index, shadow keeps getting hidden by other content
I have that problem, that on my header the box shadow isn't visible because my navigation content lays on top of it, event though my header has a higher z-index. I cant't see what exactly is the issue here, shouldn't this work? Here is an example of my issue:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sticky Element with Navigation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .sticky-header {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1000; /* Ensure this is high enough */
            background: white;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);            
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .absolute-nav-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1; /* Ensure this is lower than the sticky header */
        }

        .navigation {
            background: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .content {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky-header">
        Sticky Header
        <div class="absolute-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="navigation">
                Navigation Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Page content goes here...</p>
        <p>More content...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



If you remove this part:
<div class="absolute-nav-wrapper">
        <div class="navigation">
            Navigation Content
        </div>
 </div>

the shadow shows up again.

But why you have such a bad html structure. If you simply create Navigation Content below sticky header your problem will be solved. This html doesn't make sense at all. You have added  top: 100% to absolute-nav-wrapper instead you just add top: 110% then also your issue will be fixed.

@Meet Yes the setup is kind of weird but it already existed before I started working on it so I dont really want to change everything just for the shadow, sind in the original version there is even more logic and JS for this header :/

Do you want your navigation below the header?

@MrJoky yes so its displayed underneath it but as I said I cant really change the structure (so I cant move it out of the header) cause that messes up the whole styling and JS

Unsure why you can't change it. If you do changes it is clear that you have to adapt the CSS and JS.

@Rugo this will never work because you cannot put parent component above child component, its not possible in html css. You can rearrange parent - parent , child - child or child above parent but parent above child is not possible. Do consider restructuring html and if you consider please share.

There is no point in trying to use z-index on the heading or the children as they can't go behind (in the z axis sense) their parent.
If you want to keep that HTML structure then you could put the shadow on an after pseudo element instead of on the element itself. That will ensure that it comes above the children.
With this adjustment the rest of the CSS can remain as-is.
This snippet adds some more content so the stickiness can be checked.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sticky Element with Navigation</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sticky-header {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .sticky-header::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    }
    
    .absolute-nav-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navigation {
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .content {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sticky-header">
    Sticky Header
    <div class="absolute-nav-wrapper">
      <div class="navigation">
        Navigation Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Page content goes here...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Thank you this works fine! In my case I also needed to add pointer-events: none; because my navigation would not work on hover anymore :)

As meet mentioned… your HTML structure is not the best. I've made you an example for an easy semantic HTML structure. You can put everything in a div too and give it a class. But this makes the code a little bit cleaner.
Let's switch to your problem. Because of this poor layout and a few unnecessary properties, nothing works. There is no need for z-index (as long as there are no other elements with a z-index). Especially a z-index: -1 for an element which the user wants to interact with is a terrible practice.
I just need one selector for the header to make it work with the shadow and the sticky behavior.
This is all I could read out of your question. Hope this answer helps you.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 2rem;
}

main {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.sticky-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #cecece;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px 1px #000;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
<header class="sticky-header">
  <p>Sticky Header</p>

</header>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="content-container">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/31343C" style="margin: 5rem 0;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>&copy; everyone who knows HTML</p>
</footer>




Sorry maybe I wrote this not that well but I need the navigation to be a seperate row beneath the the header itself, not inside it. And underneath the header (not the navigation) I need the shadow. So the shadow of the header should be above the navigation, so that it acts as a seperation between the two.

I edited it. Now the navigation is in a seperat row and underneath the header.
